# Select a table row on input value

Tags: jquery, select, input, row

I'm trying to select a row based on a condition that says something like 'if the user inform any value (number, of course), then the row is selected, else the row stays normal.' But it's not working very well. When i add a value it works fine only in the first input, if i start on the 3rd for example, it doesnt work. Someone can help me?

(please correct my english if it's not right)

http://jsfiddle.net/ccarizzo/hX4nu/60/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working at the link provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referring to the class within the function, use $(this):

```
$(function () {
    $('input.qtd').keyup(function () {       
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
             $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected");
        }

         else if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("selected");
        }              
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hX4nu/61/)**.

Comment: thank you, seems to work fine now. Do you know how can I make it selected when the user use the arrow up and down from the input field too?

Comment: Hmmm, do you mean the tab key or arrows? When I use arrows on the form it doesn't move the cursor.